# LMAX Disruptor in Python

Tags: python-3.x, disruptor-pattern, lmax

Is there already an implementation (or at least binding to) Python3?

I can see that an original implementation is in Java on Github, but I do not see anything for Python3.

Answer (score 2):

simple cython-based implementation is provided by **data-pipe**:

- https://pypi.org/project/data-pipe/
- https://github.com/random-python/data_pipe

Comment: 1) No, this not complete disruptor, rather a capability demonstration. 2) there is no atomic/locking by design 3) yes, there are memory barriers, see native_any.h. 4) Internally, we have developed single producer / multiple consumer variation, still no atomic/locking needed, works both with cross-thread and cross-process profile.

Comment: My bad, I did not analyze the code structure thoroughly enough. Not familiar with Cython extensions, *.pxd and *.pyx files confused me :)

Comment: After checking again, `native_any.h` and `native_any.pxd` define `native_bool_compare_swap_int` to expose the GCC compiler intrinsic. But as far as I can tell, this function is never used in any other file. Same for `native_synchronize`. Can you please explain how this works?